# node js calling same deferred function from client and another node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, q

Is there a better way to call the same function from the client and another node js module. Without having 2 separate functions. The only difference method the value is returned?

```
        exports.getFiles = function(req,res){
            var globPattern = req.body.globPattern;
            var globOptions =req.body.globOptions;
            glob(globPattern, globOptions, function (err, files) {
                if(err)
                    {
                        res.status(400);
                        winston.log('error', err);
                        return res.send({success:false,reason: err});
                    }
                res.send({success:true,data:files});
            });
        };
        exports.getFilesFunc = function(payload){
            var deferred = q.defer();
            var globPattern = payload.globPattern;
            var globOptions = payload.globOptions;
            glob(globPattern, globOptions, function (err, files) {
                if(err)
                    deferred.resolve({success:false,reason: err});
                deferred.resolve({success:true,data: files});
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Comment: You should not resolve a deferred with `false` when there is an error. Just reject it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically call `getFilesFunc` from `getFiles`:

```
exports.getFilesFunc = function(payload){
    return Q.nfcall(glob, payload.globPattern, payload.globOptions);
};
exports.getFiles = function(req,res){
    this.getFilesFunct(req.body).then(function(files) {
        res.send({success:true, data:files});
    }, function(err) {
        res.status(400);
        winston.log('error', err);
        return res.send({success:false, reason: err});
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Promises, you can shorten your code to the following:

```
var Q = require('q'),
    glob = Q.denodeify(require('glob'));

exports.getFiles = function(pattern, options) {
    return glob(pattern, options);
};
```

Then in your controller, or wherever you're calling the function you'd control what you're going to do with your retured data:

```
module
    .getfiles(req.body.globPattern, req.body.globOptions)
    //or .getFiles(payload.globPattern, payload.globOptions)
    .then(function (files) {

    }, function (error) {

    });
```